# Getting error on inserting data on table using SQLite

Tags: android, database, sqlite, insert

I'm building android mobile app and I use SQLite as its database. I'm having trouble inserting record on a table and it returns a Toast message which is **"Insert failed"** meaning saving data was unsuccessful.

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MobileBuddy.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "bets_table";
    public static final String COL_1 = "COMBINATION";
    public static final String COL_2 = "DRAW_DATE";
    public static final String COL_3 = "TRANS_DATE";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + COL_1 + " TEXT, " + COL_2 + " DATETIME, " + COL_3 + " DATETIME)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean insertBetData(String combination, String drawDate, String transDate) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_1, combination);
        contentValues.put(COL_2, drawDate);
        contentValues.put(COL_3, transDate);
        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
        if (result == 1) return true; else return false;
    }
}
```

I used the code below in an onClick event and this should trigger an insertion of data on a table.

```
calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
boolean isSave = lottoDb.insertBetData(validBet, sdf.format(calendar.getTime()), sdf.format(calendar.getTime()));
if (isSave == true)
    Toast.makeText(PlaySixNumbers.this, "Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
else
    Toast.makeText(PlaySixNumbers.this, "Insert failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

What's wrong with my codes? Hope you understand my inquiry..

Comment: attach your logcat output

Comment: try to put,.. sdf.format(calendar.getTime())  into  one  String...and pass this  String  to your  insertMethod

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried this morning to run/test the app using an emulator. Fortunately, **it works**. I guess the problem is with my device or android phone. Either it has limited space or some kind of a permission. But i'm okay now and thanks to all answers.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues)) says that the `insert()` function returns

> the row ID of the newly inserted row, or -1 if an error occurred

The ID is not necessarily `1`. You have to check that the return value is not the error value.

And it would be a better idea to use `insertOrThrow()` instead to get a useful error message.

Answer (score 0):

Change your if condition as follows :

```
public boolean insertBetData(String combination, String drawDate, String transDate) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_1, combination);
        contentValues.put(COL_2, drawDate);
        contentValues.put(COL_3, transDate);
        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
        if (result >= 1) return true; else return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your **Insert** Method

```
public Integer insertBetData(String combination, String drawDate, String transDate) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_1, combination);
        contentValues.put(COL_2, drawDate);
        contentValues.put(COL_3, transDate);
        long BetId = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
        return BetId;
}
```

and Use **Insert** method as below :

```
calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
    String drawDate = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
    String transDate = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
    Integer BetId = lottoDb.insertBetData(validBet,drawDate,transDate );
    Toast.makeText(PlaySixNumbers.this, "Inserted Id is "+ BetId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Now, Check this **BetId**  if it return's greater than Zero then your **insert** is Correct.else not Correct.